# Kibana deployment issue on server . . . client not able to access GUI

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have configured Logstash + ES + kibana on 100.100.0.158 VM and Kibana is running under apache server. port 8080

Now what my need is . . I just have to give URL "100.100.0.158:8080/kibana" to client so client can see his data on web.

When when I put this URL on client browser I am getting this error 
"can't contact elasticsearch at http://"127.0.0.1":9200 please ensure that elastic search is reachable from your system"

Do I need to configure ES with IP 100.100.0.158:9200 or 127.0.0.1:9200 is ok . . !

Help . . !

Thanks
Tushar

Answer (score 4):

If your Kibana and ES are installed on the same box, you can have it auto-detect the the ES URL/IP by using this line in your Kibana's config.js file:

```
/** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
 * ==== elasticsearch
 *
 * The URL to your elasticsearch server. You almost certainly don't
 * want +http://localhost:9200+ here. Even if Kibana and Elasticsearch are on
 * the same host. By default this will attempt to reach ES at the same host you have
 * elasticsearch installed on. You probably want to set it to the FQDN of your
 * elasticsearch host
 */
elasticsearch: "http://"+window.location.hostname+":9200",
```

This is because the interface between Kibana and ES is via JavaScript, and so using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` actually points to the client machine (that the browser is running on) rather than the server.

Comment: Thanks . . but my ES + kibana is running successfully on .158 server . . my client machine is .159 and what i want is Open Client browser type the server URL "100.100.0.158:8080/kibana" and see the logs.

Comment: Yes understood. When your .159 client accesses the server at .158, the config above will take the hostname from your browser window (in this case .158) and use that as the ES server and it will work.  When you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it will actually point to your client (.159) machine.

Answer (score 2):

Modify elasticsearch configuration file elasticsearch.yml

Append or modify following configurations:

```
# Enable or disable cross-origin resource sharing.
http.cors.enabled: true

# Which origins to allow.
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/<*your\.kibana\.host*>(:[0-9]+)?/
```

It is caused by kibana page trying to load jason data from elasticsearch which will be blocked for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is about iptables rules. Kibana uses 9292 for web port, but for elasticsearch queries uses 9200. So you must add line to iptables for these ports.

```
netstat -napt | grep -i LISTEN
```

you will see these ports: 9200 9300 9301 9302 9292

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
```

see detail: http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-simple