# ElasticSearch installed---but Installing kibana on localhost?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'd like to view my machine's syslogs more beautifully on an ubuntu desktop.  I notice that all the kibana documentation is oriented towards remote servers (which makes sense).  However, how would I securely view the same information about my local machine?

Here are some things I've read that were not helpful because they were designed for remote access:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-logs-on-centos-7
- [Kibana deployment issue on server . . . client not able to access GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738076/kibana-deployment-issue-on-server-client-not-able-to-access-gui)
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/installation/ which has the following problems:
- - there is no config.js to open in an editor per step 2, you can see this very plainly on their github page: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana
- - running
    ~/kibana/src/server/bin$ bash kibana.sh
    The Kibana Backend is starting up... be patient
    Error: Unable to access jarfile ./../lib/kibana.jar

How do I install kibana locally?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but for future searchers:

What you can do is download elasticsearch - http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/

Extract it, and create a plugins subdirectory. Then, within the /plugins directory create a `/kibana/_site` subdirectory.

Then, download kibana using the above mentioned link. Extract the archive, then edit config.js to point to the localhost as the elasticsearch host:

`elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200",`

Copy all of the contents of the folder you extracted kibana into to the `/kibana/_site` directory you created inside the elasticsearch folder.

Then start elasticsearch:

within the elasticsearch directory -

`bin/elasticsearch`

Kibana will now run off of the same 'server' as elasticsearch, on your local host.

UPDATE: Kibana 4 comes bundled with a web server now: see [the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/)

Comment: plugins is a file & not a directory

Comment: Correct @PiyushMattoo, you will have to create the directory. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html Goes into detail. I have edited my answer. The newest version of Kibana ships with a webserver of it's own as well.